# Highstock yAxis auto-scale issue

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart as in following image. My data are in interval 50-51. But yAxis is started from 0. I didn't set yAxis min value.

I can't set static min and max values for yAxis because of single chart can display different data series with distinct min-max values.

I'd like yAxis in this example starts from 50 or 49 and ends with 51 or 52. And Higchcarts should do it automatically.

Any ideas?

[image: yAxis auto scale]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to do some pre-processing. If you data series are not "live" then you could parse through all the y-values in all series and get the min/max and then assign those to your yAxis min and max parameters.
If your data is "live" (updated every x seconds or something) then you will need to check the new value to see if it is within the min/max range and if not, then assign a new min or max.

Comment: I have not "live" data, but mentioned chart is created as the column chart with about 1700 points. So it's costly to do additional preprocessing. Moreover with zoom I'm loading new data set from server.

Comment: Cost is relative - if you are getting this data from a DB you can pull out the min/max easily and pass it with your dataset. If you are not getting it from a DB and instead from a flat source you could get your min/max while generating your series of data. On zoom why are you fetching back to get data? Is it because your initial un-zoomed data is just the extrapolated superset of a more detailed set of data? We will need to know what your data extraction/parsing process is to provide better info.

Comment: We use fetching data from database while zooming because of initial data is more aggregated set. We store data of monitoring realtime device. New record is appearing each second. Therefore we store it in RRD database. So it's difficult to retreive max and min values from database because of it is not relational.

Comment: Well, it looks like you will need to do some pre-processing then regardless. Once you get your new point see if it is in the previous min/max range and adjust accordingly. Do the same when selecting a range on zoom.